# Change color of the active item in the Fragment Navigation Menu on Android

Tags: java, android, css, xml, android-fragments

I try to develop a basic application to Android. I stuck at changing of the UI. My concrete problem is that I can not change the default blue color of active or selected item in fragment navigation bar.

I generated my application by Android Studio and at the end I chosen the "Fragment Navigation Bar" option. So it created the base of my app.

Fragment class:

```java
    public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            /*view.setSelected(true);
            selectItem(position);*/

        }
    });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
            }
    ));
    //mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
            }

            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return getActivity().getActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    /**
     * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
     */
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.my.app.MainActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.my.app.NavigationDrawerFragment" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml:

```xml
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    tools:context="com.my.app.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/playground"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:max="100"
    android:id="@+id/loader"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_navigation_drawer.xml:

```xml
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:background="@drawable/fragment_navigation_background"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/fragment_navigation_background"
    tools:context="com.my.app.NavigationDrawerFragment">
</ListView>
```

fragment_navigation_background.xml in drawable:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
    android:state_above_anchor="true"
    android:drawable="@color/selected_menu_color2"/>
    <item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@color/selected_menu_color2"/>
    <item
    android:state_accelerated="true"
    android:drawable="@color/selected_menu_color2"/>
    <item
    android:state_hovered="true"
    android:drawable="@color/selected_menu_color2"/>
    <item
    android:state_active="true"
    android:drawable="@color/selected_menu_color2"/>
    <item
    android:state_activated="true"
    android:drawable="@color/selected_menu_color2"/>
    <item
    android:state_last="true"
    android:drawable="@color/selected_menu_color2"/>
    <item
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@color/selected_menu_color"/>
    <item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@color/selected_menu_color"/>
    <item
    android:state_single="true"
    android:drawable="@color/selected_menu_color"/>
    <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/selected_menu_color2" />
</selector>
```

style.xml in values:

```xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#cccccc</item>
    <item name="android:state_selected">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:state_above_anchor">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:state_accelerated">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:state_activated">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:state_active">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:state_checkable">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:state_checked">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:state_single">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:state_pressed">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:state_first">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:state_window_focused">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:state_focused">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:startColor">@color/selected_menu_color</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>
    <item name="android:fadingEdge">none</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

It has some effects. I can coloring the background of the whole fragment wrapper or the selected/visited/clicked items in fragment but active fragment nav item. I can not change it from blue to something else.

Comment: See https://github.com/milosmns/silly-android and look for the `Coloring.java` class. If you have a specific request that's not covered by what's in there, feel free to create a new task and we can discuss it there :) Hope this helps a bit.